# How to add an offset in the v-for loop within html with vue

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, vue.js, v-for

So the problem I'm having is within the `v-for` function of vue. I would like to be able to add an offset to the number that is then added to the table that I am creating. I feel like I might be just going in the wrong direction with this problem.

HTML Code for the table section referred to:

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="n in parseInt(recordCount)">
      <td class="idNum">
         {{ n }}
      </td>
      <td v-for="select in controlArray">
         <select v-model="selected[n][select][n]">
            <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
               {{ option.text }}
            </option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td v-for="input in controlArray">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="valueArray[n][input][n]" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

The specific problem is where I create `v-for="n in parseInt(recordCount)"`. The `n` variable isn't initialized while the `recordCount` variable is a number that can be chosen by the user.

I would like to be able to add an offset to the front of the number so that instead of iterating from 0 it could start at a higher number.

Like I said before I feel like I might be going in the wrong direction with this if someone could send my the right way I would be thankful.

Comment: Make a `computed` to generate the array you want to iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

Construction like `v-for="n in 10"` is a special Range construction, it will be repeated 10 times, starting from `n=1` and ending with `n=10`.

If you want to iterate over custom range you could just call a method to generate it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    recordCount: 10,
  },
  methods: {
    createRange(startFrom, endWith) {
      const r = [];
      for(let i = startFrom; i <= endWith; i++) {
        r.push(i);
      }
      return r;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app { padding: 10px; }
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; }
li { margin: 4px 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>Record Count: <input v-model="recordCount"/></label>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="n in createRange(5, recordCount)">
      {{ n }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: One-liner: `return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((item, index) => index + start);`

Answer (score 0):

For not-too-big offsets you can provide a `v-if` beside your `v-for`:

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="n in (parseInt(recordCount) + offset)" v-if="n > offset">
      <td class="idNum">
         {{ n }}
      </td>

      <!-- rest of your HTML -->

   </tr>
</tbody>
```